Mount Qnap shared folder permanently (after restat)
Hello I have small issue,
I use such command to mount volume:
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.50/test-folder /mnt/test-folder -o uid=myuid,username=qnapuser,password=qnappassword

Its working perectly till first reboot - how can I mount it permenently ?

You can mount at startup by modifying the fstab file.
The /etc/fstab file is used to display and edit the system mounts.
The important thing is not to touch anything that is already written.
Open the file in a terminal with temporary administrator permissions, running:
sudo nano /etc/fstab

Start editing from the bottom, adding the necessary line, change the server, data, etc. data to your own:
//server/data /local cifs username=sambauser,password=paswd,iocharset=utf8,uid=localuser,gid=localgroup,forceuid,forcegid,cifsacl,noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev 0 0

You can see that it has the same data that you use with mount just with a different structure.
It is important that you put all your configuration in that order and with the same spacing to avoid problems.
At the end there are five new parameters.
noauto,x-systemd.automount: The first indicates that it should not be mounted automatically when the system boots, because it can significantly slow down the startup. The second tells the kernel to only mount the partition when it is going to be accessed for the first time, so even though for us it continues to mount automatically it does not slow down the system.
_netdev: Indicates that the partition depends directly on the network, so it should not be mounted if the network is not prepared to communicate with other devices and thus avoid errors.
0 0: The two zeros are essential.
